# How di I find 10th trackpoint in a gpx file

Tags: php, gpx

I am showing the starting points of gpx files on a [map](https://polten.be/kaart/). I'm using the following code to extract the first track point of the files:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($gpx);
foreach ($xml->trk->trkseg->trkpt as $pt){
    $lat = (string) $pt['lat'];
    $lon = (string) $pt['lon'];
    break;
}
```

This works good but many gpx tracks start from the same spot (parking place ...) and that makes the map messy. This could be improved when I were able to show another track point (10th or 50th ..) but I can't find the code. Can you help me to extract the 10th track point from the gpx files?

Comment: ___but I can't find the code___ Thats when you have to write something for yourself using what you learned from the other code you scraped from the internet. Not everything is out there for you to borrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although SimpleXMLElement objects aren't arrays, they're designed to act like them in reasonably intuitive ways.

So, just as looping over elements with the same name is like looping over an array, accessing the 10th element with the same name is as simple as accessing 10th item in an array. Just remember to start counting at 0, not 1:

```php
$tenth = $xml->trk->trkseg->trkpt[9];
```

Note that your current code can be simplified because it always gets the first item:

```php
$pt = $xml->trk->trkseg->trkpt[0];
$lat = (string) $pt['lat'];
$lon = (string) $pt['lon'];
```

In fact, SimpleXML assumes you want the first match if you don't say otherwise, so the following are all equivalent:

```php
$pt = $xml->trk->trkseg->trkpt;
$pt = $xml->trk->trkseg->trkpt[0];
$pt = $xml->trk->trkseg[0]->trkpt[0];
$pt = $xml->trk[0]->trkseg[0]->trkpt[0];
$pt = $xml->trk[0]->trkseg[0]->trkpt;
// etc
```

Comment: This does the job. Thanks for explaining, this helps me to understand how things work.